# Script for Selecting random data from a list on button press

Tags: random, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps-script-editor

I'm creating a spreadsheet which can automatically select random cell data from a particular column when I press a button. However, I cannot figure out the script.

Thanks to some friends I've tried a few variations that involve using add-ons but ideally I don't want to use anything like that as it needs to be usable if people wanted to make a copy without the addons.

What I'm looking to do is click a particular button and then the adjacent cell displays a random value from the data set given in the list.

I have two sheets. "Interface" and "Under the Hood" - Pretty self-explanatory, Interface has the buttons and Under the hood contains the data.

Here is some code that I've found elsewhere online, trying to use this as a base.

```
  function random() {
      var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()
      var val=ss.getRange("A1").getValue()
      var clr =ss.getRange("A1").clearContent()
      ss.getRange("A1").setValue(val)
    }
```

To throw an example out there -

A2-A33 is our data setlist (Under the Hood sheet)

I Have drawn a button and I would like the random selection to appear in cell D17 (interface).

Dummy Data: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HMmT_dx2_zeDKozEeDElYLaZutc4ruSwjjvVjyGg-Ls/edit?usp=sharing

Can anybody walk me through how to do this?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by a random selection. Do you want a random row, a random column or a random cell.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Apologies If I didn't make it clear enough. I've got a list of data in cells A2-A33 in a separate sheet (sheet A) (for example). 

In Sheet B I have a button, when I press that button I would like a random selection to appear in cell D17 (Sheet B) from the aforementioned list.

Comment: Yes I finally figured it after looking at the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function getRandomValue(searchColumn,resultCellRow,resultCellColumn) {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var dsh=ss.getSheetByName('Interface');
  var ssh=ss.getSheetByName('UnderTheHood')
  var rg=ssh.getRange(2,searchColumn,ssh.getLastRow()-1,1);
  var vA=rg.getValues().map(function(r){return r[0]});
  while(vA[vA.length-1].length==0) {
    vA.splice(vA.length-1,1);
  }
  dsh.getRange(resultCellRow,resultCellColumn).setValue( vA[Math.floor(Math.random()*vA.length)]);
}

function generateCoach() {
  getRandomValue(10,3,4)
}

function coachBackStory() {
  getRandomValue(11,5,4)
}

function contracts() {
  getRandomValue(7,5,8);
}
```

I presume that you can figure out the rest of the functions for the various buttons.  All you need to do is give it the column to search in "UnderTheHood" and the cell to put answer in "Interface"

Comment: I really appreciate you helping me here, unfortunately, I received this error "TypeError: Cannot call method "getRange" of null."

This is the sheet I'm currently working from (just in case that make any difference). - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PQlQu7Kmv7FD_zmKMHp2KSjpuJyWOsj1O82fFeHbXIE/edit?usp=sharing

Would it be possible for you to explain to me within that code where I select the data range and where I select the output cell?

Comment: I just made some changes when I realized that I need to get the unique column heights rather that use the sheet.getLastRow().  And I'm working from the sheet that was in your question

Comment: You basically, just need to tell the getRandomValue() function the column to search in "UnderTheHood" and the row and column to put it into in "Interface".

Comment: Thank you @cooper, I'll give it ago now and see what happens!

I'm just learning this stuff and I took on a task that is way out of my depth lol.

Comment: On your new sheet `function generateCoach() { getRandomValue(10,17,2);}` And also change "UnderTheHood" to "UTH"

Comment: May I ask you one more queston? A very obvious one at that? In this statement "getRandomValue(11,21,3)" what do the numbers refer to? I know they refer to rows and columns and the output cell, I'm just not sure on the order they're done here, thank you.

also, is it any different for merged cells? or should I avoid those?

Comment: The first parameter is 12 and that is the column number in "UTH" to search.  The second parameter is the row number of the cell the result will be place into in "Interface" and the third parameter is the column number of that cell.

Comment: Thank you very much sir, on that note, I assume it would make sense to remove the titles from the UTH data sets? otherwise they would be included in the randomisation, correct?

Comment: No, you can leave the titles because I search from row 2 to the bottom of each column.